# What is wrong with this multi-threaded, synchronized code?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class Counting {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        class Counter {
            private int count = 0;

            synchronized public void increment() {
                ++count;
            }

            public int getCount() {
                return count;
            }
        }
        final Counter counter = new Counter();
        class CountingThread extends Thread {
            public void run() {
                for (int x = 0; x < 10000; ++x)
                    counter.increment();
            }
        }
        CountingThread t1 = new CountingThread();
        CountingThread t2 = new CountingThread();
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        System.out.println(counter.getCount());
    }
}
```

I am reading my text book on concurrency, and I am confused by this example. Here I have counter class being shared by many threads. Since there will be race condition in increment method, we make it synchronized, so that only one thread accesses it at one time. However, according to the book, the method getCount() should also be synchronized. I am not able to understand why that is the case? What is the issue that will occur, if getCount is not synchronized?

Edit :The book says, without making getCount synchronized, we might see stale data.

Comment: In this example, nothing. But what if there was a third thread that called `getCount` repeatedly?

Comment: @immibis Could you explain what will happen in that case? I am new to multi-threading.

Comment: @Dude - `Thread.join()` ensures a *happens-before* relationship. Thus the changes made by one thread will be visible to another. If you have another thread which is calling `getCOunt()` repeatedly, then your main thread is the only thread that is ensured to see the changes (since other threads join in it) , for any other thread, a *happens-before* might not exist and thus a stale value might be returned.

Comment: @TheLostMind But does not synchronization also ensure happens-before? So in your example say we have a third thread repeatedly calling getCount(), shouldn't it see the changes due to synchronization as they are sharing the same object?

Comment: @Dude - Yes, *synchronization* ensures a *memory barrier / happens before*. What this means is that once the lock is released, data will be *updated* for other threads. *during execution of synchoronized block*, there is no guarantee that other threads will read  (correct) value updated by thread which holds the lock. What if thread-1 increments the counter and then stops (doesn't exit synchronized block / method) and thread -2 tries to read value of count?. *release of lock* flushes the processor cache and writes data back to the main memory.

Comment: @Dude Yes, sort of... if you  have a thread that runs `synchronized(X) {Y();}` and another thread that runs `synchronized(X) {Z();}` then either Y happens-before Z, or vice versa. If you have a thread that runs `synchronized(X) {Y();}` and another that just runs `Z();` then there is no such relationship.

Answer (score 2):

The book is wrong *in context of the example code* as `getCount` is only accessed *after* the main thread joins the threads [which ensure a happens-before.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html)

> When a thread terminates and causes a Thread.join in another thread to return, then *all the statements executed by the terminated thread have a happens-before relationship with all the statements following the successful join.* The effects of the code in the thread are now visible to the thread that performed the join.

However, making `getCount` synchronized - while still not useful in an atomic get-and-increment-if - will ensure visibility in some *other* cases without a happens-before guarantee. If there is no happens-before guarantee a 'stale' value *might* be returned .. but that's not guaranteed either.

Comment: So you are saying that since getCount is being called from the main thread, the count object it may see, it might be different from the count object we modified in the two threads? Is that reasoning right?

Comment: @Dude Since it is being called from the thread *after* the joins returned (on it). If the threads were not explicitly joined, but say there was a `sleep` until the 'threads stopped running', then there would *not* be a happens-before guarantee. The guarantee is not strictly due to *a* join, but rather it is between the thread doing the join and the terminated thread.

Comment: Happens before would not cause the value of count to be updated on the main thread.

Comment: @Dude Thus the reasoning about 'might see a different count [value]' is right in some *other* context, yes. But not in the example code.